# Superfluous axioms for ribbon Hopf algebra

Tags: qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, quantum-groups, ribbon-hopf-algebras

In his book *Foundations of quantum group theory*, Majid defines (2.1.10)  a ribbon Hopf algebra as a quasi-triangular Hopf algebra $(H, R)$ with a special central element $v \in H$  satisfying

(1) $v^2 = u S(u)$ ($u$ being the Drinfeld element),

(2) $\Delta v = (R_{21}R_{12})^{-1}v  \otimes v$,

(3) $\varepsilon v =1$,

(4) $Sv=v$.

He claims (without proof) that the axioms are not independent, namely:

> **Claim 1:** (1), (2) imply (4)

> **Claim 2:** (2), (3), (4) imply (1)

I was able neither to prove the claims nor to find some reference where this is done. Can anyone help with a proof/reference?